# How do I send a Ctrl+Alt+Delete when connected from the Screen Sharing app to a Windows computer?

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, screen-sharing, remote-control

When using Apple's Screen Sharing application to connect to a Windows computer that is running VNC, how do I send a Ctrl+Alt+Delete to the Windows computer?  I've tried a number of key sequences and none of them are working.

Answer (score 4):

After some searching, I found the answer.  On the mac keyboard, you have to press

**Ctrl + Option (Alt) + Command + Delete**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option (alt)</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>delete ⌦</kbd>

Comment: And a two finger tap = a right-click, when connected to an RDP session

Answer (score 1):

One handy tool when remoting to Windows is to use the On Screen Keyboard.  Just hit the Windows Key icon, and type 'OSK' and hit Enter.  This will let you invoke any key combinations you need.